# how to clear a data in tableviewcell again start reload?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitableview

i'm developing a bluetooth apps.1) I want to hide a tableview when i start the apps..after i pressed a action button i want to enable a tableview.. 2)if i again press a action button means tableviewcell clear the data and show empty before searching..give me an idea..

some of the code-

```
- (IBAction)connectButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
[self.deviceTable reloadData];
self.connectButton.enabled = YES;
[self.deviceTable reloadData];
peripheralManager = [[PeripheralManager alloc] init];
peripheralManager.delegate = self;

[peripheralManager scanForPeripheralsAndConnect];
[self.deviceTable reloadData];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(float)5.0 target:self selector:@selector       (connectionTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bluetooth" message:@"Scanning" delegate:nil    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIActivityIndicatorView *progress=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
[alert addSubview:progress];
[progress startAnimating];
[alert show];
}
```

tableview

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [device count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil)
{
cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
cell.textLabel.text=[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
return cell;
}
```

TableView Delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableDetails" sender:tableView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If you want to hide table View before clicking a button you can use

`tableView.hidden=YES;`
 and inside

`- (IBAction)connectButtonTouched:(id)sender`, you can make it visible by using

```
tableView.hidden=NO;
[tableView reloadData]
```

OR

2.If you are developing app for iPad, then you can use `UIPopOverController` to show the data. You can load the `tableView` inside `UIPopOverController`  when button is clicked.

Comment: Ya.. thats what. in `- (void)viewDidLoad` set `tableView.hidden=YES;`

Comment: If you want to reload the data. `[tableView reloadData]`. Before that, remove all the objects in `device` array which you have specified. To remove all the objects, `device` variable you declared should be `NSMutableArray` i.e., `[device removeAllObjects]`

Comment: first time search part finished then shows data in tableview and again i pressed the search part the data disappears.i dont know why?

Comment: Ya. when you click on search again. First remove data from the array, then `[tableView reloadData]` then everytime new result is found add that result into the `device` array. Every time you add ,again you call `[tableView reloadData]`

Comment: yes correct but first time work properly next time data remove from the tableview and not displayed again..

Answer (score 0):

Add **BOOL flag** in .h file

Now in ViewDidLoad add this:

```
flag = FALSE;
```

in tableview delegate method

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if(flag)
     return [device count];
   else
     return 0;
}
```

In your button action method:

```
 - (IBAction)connectButtonTouched:(id)sender
 {
    if(!flag)
       flag = TRUE;
    else
       flag = FALSE;

    [self.deviceTable reloadData];
    //your other code here
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..error:use of undeclared identifier'flag'

Comment: it will automatically reuse cell

Answer (score 0):

if they are in the same view, why not give the tableView a alpha of 0 and userInteractionEnabled = NO ?

Although, I think it would be easier if, instead of linking your tableView from interface builder, keep it as a member and initialize/reinitialize it when you tap your button.

something like: 
`- (IBAction)connectButtonTouched:(id)sender {

if (self.deviceTable) {
   [self.deviceTable removefromSuperview];
   self.deviceTable = nil; 
}

self.deviceTable = [[UITableView alloc] init];

// and so on
`

Also you might put another method in peripheralManager delegate ... something like 
-(void)didFinishScanning and inside redraw your table view.

I hope I understood the question well, and helped you in any way

Comment: just reloadData on the tableView